# Parsing comma separated strings with spaces

Tags: c, parsing, scanf

I need to parse a string that contains two integers and two strings, all separated by commas.  The strings contain spaces which is causing issues.  Format is integer, strings[including spaces], string[including spaces], integer.  Working on Linux with gcc, c99 standard.

I've tried parsing with various regex style parsing methods.  I have solution that works if the strings don't have spaces but breaks when spaces are involved.

```
char *line = "5,some text, some more text with spaces, 3";
int num1, num2;
char string1[max_size];
char string2[max_size];

sscanf(line, "%d,%[^,],%[^,],%d", &num1, string1, string2, &num2);
```

I expect the variables to contain:

```
num1 == 5;
string1 == "some text";
string2 == "some more text with spaces";
num2 == 3;
```

I am not getting compilation errors or anything, but I am getting issues where if there are any spaces, the data becomes junk.

Comment: Would you consider using something other than `scanf`?  It's a pretty poor tool, and if you're doing anything at all complicated, I find it's usually more trouble than it's worth.  One option here (although it's also imperfect) is [`strtok`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok); another is [`strsep`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strsep).

Comment: Definitely open to it, but limited in the libraries I can use.  I'm also trying out implementations with strtok but not having luck.

Comment: When I try your sample program, before rewriting anything, I get more or less the expected output.  An extra space in `" some more text..."`, but nothing I'd consider "junk".  What sorts of cases are you having the most trouble with?

Comment: So, please be gentle, but i am using this in a function... the function gets called by some other code that is parses a text file. I think I'm initially causing the text file to incorrectly parse.

Comment: Don't worry, I won't take your head off, and I appreciate that you tried to create a small and self-contained example.  But if the small and self-contained example doesn't demonstrate the problem, if the problem only shows up using the larger program that I can't see, then I doubt I (or anyone here) is going to be able to help you, either...

Comment: Yep, I fixed the original parsing code now and it's all good.  Thank you for pointing it out and you ultimately solved the problem by making me realize this wasn't the problem.  Have a great day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a straightforward rewrite of your code to use `strtok`:

```
char line[] = "5,some text, some more text with spaces, 3";
int num1, num2;
char *string1;
char *string2;

num1 = atoi(strtok(line, ","));
string1 = strtok(NULL, ",");
string2 = strtok(NULL, ",");
num2 = atoi(strtok(NULL, ","));

printf("num1 = %d\n", num1);
printf("str1 = \"%s\"\n", string1);
printf("str2 = \"%s\"\n", string2);
printf("num2 = %d\n", num2);
```

This works, although it has these limitations:

- I'm not checking `strtok`'s return value to see if it returns NULL prematurely (indicating fewer than 4 fields in the input)
- `atoi` has no error handling, either, and will quietly return 0 if the numeric fields aren't numeric
- overall, `strtok` is a pretty poor function, too (its statefulness is quite lame)
- `strtok` basically skips over empty fields, which probably isn't what you want here (if the input line were for example something like `"12,string,,34"`)

Nevertheless, this is probably a step better than trying to use `sscanf`.

Note also that I changed `line` to an array, so that it's modifiable, since `strtok` inserts `\0` characters into it to terminate the strings it tokenizes.  (That's why `string1` and `string2` can be pointers now.)

Comment: Thank you for the help!